# How to properly iterate over a for loop using Dask?

Tags: pandas, dask, numba

When I run a loop like this (see below) using dask and pandas, only the last field in the list gets evaluated. Presumably this is because of "lazy-evaluation"

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as ddf

df_dask = ddf.from_pandas(df, npartitions=16)

for field in fields:
    df_dask["column__{field}".format(field=field)] = df_dask["column"].apply(lambda _: [__ for __ in _ if (__ == field)], meta=list)
```

If I add `.compute()` to the last line:

```
df_dask["column__{field}".format(field=field)] = df_dask["column"].apply(lambda _: [__ for __ in _ if (__ == field)], meta=list).compute()
```

it then works correctly, but is this the most efficient way of doing this operation? Is there a way for Dask to add all the items from the fields list at once, and then run them in one-shot via `compute()`?

edit ---------------

Please see screenshot below for a worked example

[image]

Comment: could you explain what you are trying to specify in the `apply` line? It seems like you're trying to add a new column to the `ddf` (based on existing columns???) and would like to specify a `meta` dictionary for each column in the `ddf`, but I could be wrong. Also, if you could provide a snippet of your data, then that would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Updated the original post with a screenshot showing a worked example. The first case is pure pandas, the second is via dask without running "compute". And the third is running "compute" for each step of the for loop. Note how the results in the second loop are incorrect since compute is never called until the head request is made! The question is how to make the third loop as efficient as possible, as compute gets called three times. I would imagine that the proper solution would build three separate edges of the graph, and then compute would calculate everything in one shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to call `.compute()` at the end of your computation to trigger work.  Warning: .compute assumes that your result will fit in memory

Also, watch out, lambdas late-bind in Python, so the `field` value may end up being the same for all of your columns.

Comment: thanks for the response. The question here is when / how to call compute? Should I call it three times as in the third for loop or is there a way to only call it once? thanks

Comment: You should call compute only at the end.  I hope that this helps to answer your question.

Comment: thanks for the response, Matt! But the example I posted in the screenshot above shows what happens when you call .compute() once - it gives an incorrect result. And the only solution I was able to find was to call compute() during each iteration of the for loop, which is obviously suboptimal. So the question is how should I call the for loop efficiently? Thank you

Comment: For your particular problem I don't know.  Something else is likely going on.  I recommend looking into the late-binding lambda issue I refer to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, where string check is just a sample function that returns True/False. The issue was the late binding of lambda functions.

```
from functools import partial

def string_check(string, search):
    return search in string

search_terms = ['foo', 'bar']
for s in search_terms:
    string_check_partial = partial(string_check, search=s)
    df[s] = df['YOUR_STRING_COL'].apply(string_check_partial)
```